# makeKeyWindow vs makeKeyAndVisible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

What is the difference between `makeKeyWindow` and `makeKeyAndVisible` which are two methods of `UIWindow` ?

When will a `UIWindow` be a `keyWindow` but will not be visible?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Each `UIWindow` has a `windowLevel`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621593-windowlevel)  A window is displayed in front of each window with a lower level, and behind each window with a higher level.

But what about two windows with the same level?  The window whose level was set more recently is in front, by default.  (The documentation used to say “When a window enters a new level, it’s ordered in front of all its peers in that level.”)  The `makeKeyWindow` message makes a window key, but that window might be partially or completely hidden behind another window on the same level.  The `makeKeyAndVisible` message makes a window key, **and** moves it to be in front of any other windows on its level.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Well said . Thanks